# Google maps api v2 - how to handle 200-300 hundred markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi i have pretty large script so i wont post it all here, but i really need help, do not know what to do more ...

I have ~300 markers in the maps and they all are loading at the same time, and google can not handle or my script can not handle but i am getting "Address could not be found" in half of them even maybe for more (others loads correctly). But if i delete all apart that one everything works as should !

What to do ? Is there a way to load them few at the time step by step, or is there many markers handler or etc ? (not markersManager, i need them all to be seen in all zoom levels)

Tryed with timeout did not helped !

Some of the code :

```
function initHeadAddress(searchString) {
 if(searchString == 'undefined') {
   map.clearOverlays(); 
   var t = setTimeout("showAddress('Himmelev Bygade 78 B, 4000 Roskilde, Denmark',1,'3T Bygningsentreprise A/S','4000','Roskilde','46328328','null','www.3t.dk',null,null)",1000);
   var t = setTimeout("showAddress('Nørre Allé 51, 7760 Hurup, Denmark',4,'Idealcombi','7760','Hurup','96882500','null','http://www.idealcombi.dk/',null,null)",1000);
    ..... A LOT OF THESE HERE MORE !!!!

   // default one
   showAddress('Denmark', 0, null, null,null,null,null,null,null,searchString);
    } else {
   // if used search function
    showAddress(searchString, 0, null, null,null,null,null,null,null,searchString);
    }
}
```

ShowAddress function:

```
function showAddress(address, markerType, companyname,postnr, by, phone, fax, web, email, searchString) {
      if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              //alert("Adresse " +address+ " blev ikke fundet");
              console.log("Adresse " +address+ " blev ikke fundet");
            } else {            
                var myIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
                myIcon.shadow = null;
                myIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2)

                if (markerType == '0') {
                    myIcon.image = '/files/billeder/../Templates/Designs/Ideal2011/images/Map/googleempty.png';
                    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(18, 18);    
                }
                if (markerType == '1') {
                    myIcon.image = '/files/billeder/../Templates/Designs/Ideal2011/images/Map/googlered.png';
                    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(18, 18);


                    $('#dotRedCheckbox').click(
                        function(){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeMarker')){
                                marker.hide();
                            } else {
                                marker.show();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                else if (markerType == '2') {
                    myIcon.image = '/files/billeder/../Templates/Designs/Ideal2011/images/Map/googlelblue.png';
                    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(18, 18);

                    $('#dotlBlueCheckbox').click(
                        function(){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeMarker')){
                                marker.hide();
                            } else {
                                marker.show();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                else if (markerType == '3') {
                    myIcon.image = '/files/billeder/../Templates/Designs/Ideal2011/images/Map/googledblue.png';
                    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(18 , 18);

                    $('#dotdBlueCheckbox').click(
                        function(){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeMarker')){
                                marker.hide();
                            } else {
                                marker.show();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                else if (markerType == '4') {
                    myIcon.image = '/files/billeder/../Templates/Designs/Ideal2011/images/Map/googlegreen.png';
                    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(18, 18);

                    $('#dotGreenCheckbox').click(
                        function(){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeMarker')){
                                marker.hide();
                            } else {
                                marker.show();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                var markerOptions = { icon: myIcon };
                var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);

                marker.getPoint();

                if(markerType != 0){        
                    points.push(point);
                    markers.push(marker);       
                }

                if (markerType == 0) {
                    if(searchString == 'undefined'){
                        map.setCenter(point, 6);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(point, 13);

                        LatD = point.lat().toFixed(5);
                        LngD = point.lng().toFixed(5);

                        find_closest_marker(LatD, LngD);
                        find_closest_marker2(LatD, LngD);
                        find_closest_marker3(LatD, LngD);
                    }
                } 

                Lat = point.lat().toFixed(5);
                Lng = point.lng().toFixed(5);


                var image = '<img src="http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=thumbnail&w=85&h=70&ll='+Lat+','+Lng+'" />'; // alt="'+address+'"

                map.addOverlay(marker);

                if(markerType != 0) {

                    if(fax != "" && fax != null && fax != 'null'){
                        var newfax = "Mob.: "+fax+"<br/>";
                    } else {
                        var newfax = "";    
                    };
                    if(web != "" && web != null && web != 'null'){
                        var newweb = "<a href='"+web+"'>"+web+"</a><br/>";
                    } else {
                        var newweb = "";    
                    };
                    if(postnr != "" && postnr != null && postnr != 'null'){
                        var newpostnr = postnr;
                    } else {
                        var newpostnr = ""; 
                    };
                    if(phone != "" && phone != null && phone != 'null'){
                        var newphone = phone;
                    } else {
                        var newphone = "";  
                    };

                    //address = address.replace("Denmark, ","");
                    //address = address.replace(", Denmark","");
                    //address = address.replace(", 2650 Hvidovre","");
                    //address = address.replace(", Hurup","");
                    //address = address.replace("UK, ","");
                    address2 = address.split(',');
                    address = address2[0];

                    var infoboxInfo = '<div class="infoboxall"><div class="infoboxinfo"><div class="infoboxAddress">'+companyname +"</div>"+ address + '<br/>' + newpostnr + " " + by+ "<br/>" + "Tlf.: " + newphone + "<br/>" + newfax + newweb+"<a href='mailto:"+email+"'>"+email+"</a>"+'</div>' + image+'</div>';
                    //marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
                    //GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click',marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address));
                    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function()
                    {marker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoboxInfo);});

                    marker.markerType = markerType;
                    marker.title = companyname;
                    marker.address = address;
                    marker.postby = newpostnr+ " " + by;
                    marker.phone = newphone;
                    marker.fax = newfax;
                    marker.web = newweb;
                    marker.email = email;

                }

            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Anyone any ideas ? How i said script is working as should if there is 5 markers or so ... but shows only some of them when all are inserted ? Ideas ?

Comment: Google recommends that API version 3 be used.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Actually i am not very familiar with v3 is it hard to convert v2 to v3 ? :) most of the tutorials is still for v2 have any for v3 ? :)

Comment: [Everything at Google now is for version 3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html).  See my answer below.

Comment: Do you really need to geocode them every time? Are they static markers, or is it a different set of addresses every time? V2 has no problem with 300+ markers.. I maintain an app that has 340 markers that update their position every 5 seconds.. thats in V2.. no problems.

Comment: Duncan_m what do you mean by geocode everytime ? No i dont need that,  they are more or less static but they changing maybe one a month, so i can make them completely static ... have any example of yours ?

Comment: You're asking google to look up the Lat/Lng of every address every time.. you dont need to do this.. retrieve the LatLng for all of your addresses and place the markers using the Lat Lng.. it will be MUCH MUCH quicker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this as I did this in a [previous project](http://plateformesinnovie.com/?lang=en)  where the markers are loaded from the database (I use API v3 in this project but the concept is the same). Since the API accept like 5 requests at the same time from the same IP, I did a "marker queue". When a marker can't be placed because the API returns an error I put it in the queue and every second or so, I try to add the next marker from the queue until the queue is empty.

Just check the source of "gmaps3.js" in the previous link to see how I did this. If you have more questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks will check it out ! More examples better , since my v3 knowledge is not very good :) maybe anyone has something more ? tutorials with v3 or with markers loading ?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html), version 2 of the API has been deprecated and you should start using version 3.  One big plus is that you no longer need a domain specific "API key", in fact, you don't need an API key at all for version 3.

I think it's easier and cleaner than version 2. If you're familiar with jQuery and jQuery plugins, then you'll really like using Map API version 3.